# What stance values non-coercion over preventing harm?

Tags: terminology, practical-ethics

I hold a particular stance, which may or may not be consistent. I would like to know if this stance has a name.

- I believe religion is not just wrong but harmful.
- I support freedom of religion.
- I do not spend time advocating against religion.
- I would not support a ban on religion.
- I would not support government spending on religious activity.

I would summarize this as saying that I just because I think something is harmful, I don't believe it is appropriate (or practical) to force others to adopt that view, even if they are harming themselves and others.

Is there a name for this stance? Including if it's fallacious.

Comment: I don't think there is a name specially for this. On the question whether non-coercion is more important than harm prevention, I would suggest that it depends on how harmful the harm is and how coercive the coercion is.

Comment: @LudwigV that is helpful, because while writing this I realized I don't hold the same stance on all issues (I support bans in some cases)

Comment: From some aspect you are [Tolerant](https://www.sciencespo.fr/ceri/fr/content/valo-denis-lacorne-limits-tolerance) and you are a supporter of [Secular state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secular_state).

Comment: I mean in terms of the quality of the statements it's an obvious contradiction. Like the two are mutually exclusive. The question is as Ludwig V has argued whether there is a difference in quantity which like would come with some soul searching in terms of WHY you hold these views. Because it's quite weird to first give a description of how to act ethical and then not do it. Like in practical application that happens all the time humans are hypocrites but in theory at least one should be consistent.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks, I strongly suspect that tolerant (as defined by your link) with it's apparent contradictions, is exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: @haxor789 I'm thinking more about conflicting values (or logic, or illogic, or pragmatism) than hypocrisy/cowardice/etc

Comment: @haxor789 If suitably rephrased there is no contradiction. It is not that non-coercion is valued over preventing harm, but rather that different types of harm are balanced against each other. If one has "common good" as the utility, and the harm from tolerating religion is judged to be less than from coercing others to abandon it, then tolerance is ethical under standard [utilitarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utilitarianism). Choosing "the lesser of two evils" is a quite common moral stance generally.

Comment: @Conifold That's where I tried to go with quality and quantity. That there is a metaparameter that is optimized. Though the way it is phrased as absolutes makes it sound like a contradiction, as it's kinda weird to on the one hand cast something as wrong and harmful so not just confused but a threat, while at the same time categorically support it.

Comment: Well, @LeeMcGee, you could coin a new phrase for this position/stance. If you'd like a suggestion, how about calling it the *Tobacco Stance* (tobacco companies are required by law to inform the public of the dangers of tobacco, but people are still free to smoke)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stance you had described is live and let live or laissez-faire attitude towards religion. Laissez-faire is a French phrase meaning "let do" or "let it be." In the context of religion, a laissez-faire attitude towards religion would involve allowing individuals to freely practice their religion or to not practice any religion at all, without interference or coercion from the state or other authorities. This perspective is characterized by a belief in the importance of individual freedom and the idea that individuals should be free to make their own decisions and choices, even if those choices might be harmful to themselves or others. So it is worth noting here this perspective can sometimes be challenged or criticized on the grounds that it allows harmful beliefs or practices to continue unchecked, and that there may be situations in which it is necessary to take action to prevent harm or to protect the rights of individuals. However, in general, the live and let live or laissez-faire attitude can be seen as a way to promote respect and understanding between people with different beliefs and values. This perspective can also be seen as a form of tolerance or pluralism, in which individuals are willing to accept and respect the beliefs and practices of others, even if they disagree with them. It is important to note, however, that tolerance does not necessarily mean that one agrees with or approves of the beliefs or actions of others, but rather that one is willing to coexist peacefully with those who hold different views.